# Can circuit $f'$ replace circuit $f$?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, examples-counterexamples

> Assume Peter and Paul develop a circuit. Paul tries to convince Peter that $f$ may be replaced by $f'$ to save hardware resources. $$\begin{aligned} f &:= \neg x_0 \land \neg x_1 \land \neg x_2 \lor x_3 \land (x_1 \lor x_2) \lor x_0 \land \neg x_2 \land \neg x_3\\\\ f' &:= \neg x_0 \land \neg x_1 \lor x_3 \end{aligned}$$ Show that $f$ and $f'$ are not equivalent. Try finding a counterexample for the equivalence of both formulas. 
>  A counterexample is the (partial) variable assignment for which the two formulas differ. Give your counterexample as a conjunction of literals (a literal is either a variable or its negation).

---

Until now I've solved both of them individually now I am confused about how to give a counterexample.

f:  (x3 & (x1 | x2)) | (!x2 & ((!x0 & !x1) | (x0 & !x3)))

f': (!x0 & !x1) | x3

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You can post "typeset" notation for logic and math; see [this brief introduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and its links to more detailed help.  The title contains the acronym ROBDD, but this is not explained in the body of your Question.  You're being asked to find an assignment of logical values to the variables $x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3$ such that $f$ and $f'$ have different logical values.  So in the worst case you must simply try all sixteen possibilities.

Comment: Which book on propositional logic?

Comment: I think you need to add some parentheses.

Comment: Find an assignment that makes $f'$ true.  Then check if that assignment also makes $f$ true.

Comment: Okay, let me try. Thanks